# What to do Oracle Apex always use dots as decimal separator no matter what browser language is?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-19.2

What to do Oracle Apex always use dots as decimal separator no matter what browser language is?
Now in language other than EN Apex expects ',' and if dot cries '... must be numeric!'

I found on Internet that I should enter directive

```
execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''. ''';
```

in Globalization Attributes => Security => Initialization PL/SQL but it does not work. When this command there, user cannot log in.

How to set dot for no matter what user language?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Change on Globalization:

[image: Look here]

Works for me.

Comment: I made your picture visible, but now I think you need to edit the text inside it to be English.  Which would be easier if you had posted textual description instead of a picture of mostly text. Alternatively please change your GUI language to English, then make the screenshot again.

Comment: Will not work. This is only for database. Apex will keep local separators not matter what u do. You have to play with custom functions to replace decimal separators.